# Header Cookie "sid" value to a variable

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I need to extract the "sid" value from Jmeter Cookie. Below is the sample jmeter header output

```
GET htts://example.for.com/apex/AppDashboard?jl=1`
```

Cookie Data:

```
oinfo=c3RhdHVzPURlbW8mdHlwZT0yJm9pZD0wMERRMDAwMDAwR0phQkc=; logouturl=https://example.for.com/Login; disco=Q:00DQ000000GJaBG:005Q000000NwS1U:1; autocomplete=1; sid=00DQ000000GJaBG!ARoAQPklHZykcaAaJkI9prEbHROxU2CzxRfMDGKwMGpv5rZYwOOKd_GRiVRiYVYRKFTzYk6Vg0Zu48vmM5FyFSRQ4ZPtvQzR; sid_Client=000000NwS1U000000GJaBG; clientSrc=204.14.239.161; oid=00DQ000000GJaBG; apex__eventId=a0kQ0000002FecHIAS
```

Request Headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Referer: htts://example.for.com/apex/SecureLanding?eventId=a0kQ0000002FecHIAS
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: example.for.com
```

I need to extract the "sid" value from the cookie.

Answer (score 13):

One option is to use a regular expression extractor on the response headers.  You can do this by right clicking on your HTTP Request > Add > Post Processor > Regular Expression Extractor.  Fill out the fields accordingly:

1. Response Field to check: **Headers**
2. ReferenceName: **SID_VALUE**
3. Regular Expression: **sid=(.*);**
4. Template: **$1$**
5. Match No.: **1**

If the SID exists in the cookies in the response, you can access in in other samplers/tests/etc by referencing it as **${SID_VALUE}**.

Answer (score 11):

Another simplier option is adding a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) which automatically handles cookies. However you need to set `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` property either in `jmeter.properties` file or by passing a corresponding parameter to JMeter startup script i.e.

`jmeter -JCookieManager.save.cookies=true`

After that you'll see all the cookies as JMeter Variables. The easiest way to visualize them is using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener

In your case you can access your `sid` cookie as

`${COOKIE_sid}`

Other cookies can also similarly be obtained as `${COOKIE_sidClient}`, `${COOKIE_clientSrc}`, etc.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for the content. It helps me a lot. I have a Question: How to get the value of the cookie to post it in the "Request Header" as like posting the user-agent in the Header Manager(Jmeter). Cookie 
_ga=GA1.2.1710658689.1468689932 How do i find this "_ga value" I didn't get into my debug sample to find the value in Jmeter Variables.